# Is it possible to use more than XG of RAM in Java Saxon HE, PE, or EE

Tags: saxon

I have been told that there is some hard limit inside Saxon that prevents it from using more than X G of RAM. I knew there were issues with allocating more than 2G based on 32 bit vs 64 bit Java but want to know is there any truth to a limit for Saxon itself. The limit claimed was 2G but I'm looking to see if there is any limit based on Saxon or are all the limits from Java.

Comment: I am just a Saxon user, as far as I am aware, like any Java application, it uses the memory you allow it to be allocated when running it with `java.exe`, for instance with the Oracle JRE the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html suggests you can set `-Xmsn` for the initial memory and `-Xmxn` for the maximum size of the memory allocation pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no limit inside Saxon on the amount of memory you can allocate: it's whatever the Java VM will support.

However, Saxon uses Java arrays and strings, and these have a size limit imposed by the Java language specification, which allows addressing into arrays and strings using a 32-bit integer. So you may hit limits caused not by the amount of memory available, but by the maximum size of Java objects. For example, in the TinyTree data structure, the number of nodes in a tree is limited to 2^31, and the string value of the document node (that is, the concatenation of all text nodes in the document) cannot exceed 2^31 characters.